# Cross Site Scripting disturbs UI

Tags: xss

When i enter some script in textbox and hit submit button, that script executes and also disturbs the UI. I have used XSSFilter to block the suspicious text, no doubt it works partially and replaces the suspicious text, but it prints junk characters in the uI.

For Ex: I entered "alert("123");", then below is the textbox value:

and in the textbox, its displaying me only :"alert(".

My requirement is : I want the entire text to be as it is and script should not execute.

Comment: Please edit your post to clean-up the code fragments. Use backticks (`) to delimit code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode rather than filter. Sounds like the " ends the value attribute of the input tag. See the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet.